# how to set "if" criteria correctly App Script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to understand how to set "if" criteria correctly. Below script works, but only if B55 is hardcoded with "yes" or "no" words. As soon as I use formula on gsheets to arrive to yes/no on B55 script doesn't recognize the results. What would be the fix there?
And another question while on the topic (if I may) what would be the correct formula to write if B55 > 0 then unhide (again assuming B55 is formulated to arrive to certain number). Thanks!

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = e.range; 
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== 'Deal Inputs' || range.getA1Notation() == 'B55') {; 
    if (e.value === 'No') { 
      activeSheet.hideRows(56, 64);
    }  else if (e.value === 'Yes') { 
        activeSheet.showRows(56, 64); 
        } 
  }
```

Comment: Could you include in your post the formula used for B55? Also, if possible kindly share a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

An onEdit trigger always requires a user editing the spreadsheet. A change in the spreadsheet caused by the (re)calculation of a formula will not fire the onEdit trigger. [See here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)